# Zend Framework 2 How To Unit Test Doctrine 2 Entities

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, phpunit

So I am using Doctrine 2 module in Zend Framework. I got everything working inside my controllers. I can do:

```
use ModuleName\Entity\User;
```

And then in controller action:

```
$user = new User;
$user->username = 'john.doe';
$user->password = md5('password');
$this->_getEntityManager()->persist($user);
$this->_getEntityManager()->flush();
```

And it's working correctly. A new row in the database is created.

When I try the same thing inside my unit tests I get:

```
class_parents(): Class User does not exist and could not be loaded
/Users/richardknop/Projects/myproject/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php:40
/Users/richardknop/Projects/myproject/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:257
```

Any ideas? I am using the same bootstrap for my unit tests as for my application. In unit tests I extend PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

im bootsrappong my tests like this:

I have have the testsuite setup in `module/Something/tests`

**run-tests.php**

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

chdir(__DIR__);
$paths = array();
if ($argc > 1) {
    foreach ($argv as $key => $path) {

        if (!$key) continue;
        system('phpunit -c '. __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'phpunit.xml '. __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $path, $result);
        echo $result;
    }

} else {

    system('phpunit -c '. __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'phpunit.xml '. __DIR__, $result);
    echo $result;
}
```

** phpunit.xml

```
<phpunit
    bootstrap="./Bootstrap.php"
    backupGlobals="false"
    backupStaticAttributes="false"
    cacheTokens="true"
    colors="true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    forceCoversAnnotation="false"
    mapTestClassNameToCoveredClassName="false"
    processIsolation="false"
    stopOnError="false"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    stopOnIncomplete="false"
    stopOnSkipped="false"
    strict="false"
    verbose="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Module Test Suite">
            <directory>./</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

**TestConfiguration.php**

```
<?php

return array(
    'output_buffering' => false, // required for testing sessions
    'modules' => array(
        //'DoctrineModule',
        //'DoctrineORMModule',
        'Base',
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths' => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
    ),
);
```

**Boostrap.php**

```
<?php

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceManagerConfig;
use BaseModuleTest\TestCase;

error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
chdir(__DIR__);

$configuration = @include __DIR__ . '/TestConfiguration.php';
if (isset($configuration['output_buffering']) && $configuration['output_buffering']) {

    ob_start(); // required to test sessions
}

spl_autoload_register('loadTestClass', true, false);
function loadTestClass($classname) {

    $file = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $classname) . '.php';
    if (is_file($file) && is_readable($file)) {

        require_once $file;
    }
}


$previousDir = '.';
while (!file_exists('config/application.config.php')) {
    $dir = dirname(getcwd());

    if ($previousDir === $dir) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
            'Unable to locate "config/application.config.php":'
                . ' is DoctrineORMModule in a sub-directory of your application skeleton?'
        );
    }

    $previousDir = $dir;
    chdir($dir);
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

require './module/Base/src/functions.php';

if  (!@include_once 'vendor/autoload.php') {
    throw new RuntimeException('vendor/autoload.php could not be found. Did you run `php composer.phar install`?');
}

$serviceManager = new ServiceManager(new ServiceManagerConfig(
    isset($configuration['service_manager']) ? $configuration['service_manager'] : array()
));
$serviceManager->setService('ApplicationConfig', $configuration);
$serviceManager->setFactory('ServiceListener', 'Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceListenerFactory');

/** @var $moduleManager \Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager */
$moduleManager = $serviceManager->get('ModuleManager');
$moduleManager->loadModules();
$serviceManager->setAllowOverride(true);

$application = $serviceManager->get('Application');
$event  = new MvcEvent();
$event->setTarget($application);
$event->setApplication($application)
    ->setRequest($application->getRequest())
    ->setResponse($application->getResponse())
    ->setRouter($serviceManager->get('Router'));
```

Comment: Hi I am trying to use this bootstrap but the this error: LogicException: Function 'loadTestClass' not found (function 'loadTestClass' not
 found or invalid function name)